# python KeyboardInterrupt doubletaps

Tags: python

My program (on linux) under Python 2.7 has the following:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,self.stop)    # CTRL-C stop (-INT TERM)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,self.pause)  # pause
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2,self.resume) # resume
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,self.stop)   # stop
```

These all work as expected using kill - pid. However if during execution I hit CTRL-C, the stop function gets called twice.

I have even tried catching the KeyboardInterrupt exception but it never gets called.

My stop function raises an exception if it's called twice which I now have commented out but I would rather have this run without workarounds.

Any ideas?

signal handler for INT and TERM

```
def stop(self,signum=None,stack=None):
    if self._state == WASP_RUNNING or self._state == WASP_PAUSED:
        logging.info("**** Stopping Wasp ****")
        self._halt.set()
    else:
        raise WaspRuntimeException, "Wasp state %d not valid for stop" % self._state
```

the above gets called twice as the the WaspRuntimeException gets called. I have also added print statements to confirm this.

The whole program is lengthy. Below is the start function which is hopefully the important part. The **init** only sets all internal variables to None. The function _create(), reads a config file, creates the Event _halt, creates a virtual wireless nic in monitor mode, creates one child process (for now) the scanner which sets the wireless nic channel every 100ms or so. The function _destroy() destroys the virtual nic, sends a poison pill to scanner and waits for it to join.

```
def start(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,self.stop)    # CTRL-C stop
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,self.pause)  # pause
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2,self.resume) # resume
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,self.stop)   # stop

    logging.info("**** Starting Wasp ****")
    self._create()
    self._state = WASP_RUNNING
    while not self._halt.is_set():
        if self._state == WASP_RUNNING:
            if self._err.has_key('scanner'):
                logging.error("Scanner failed. (%s) %s",self._err['scanner'][0],\
                                                        self._err['scanner'][1])
                self._state = WASP_INVALID
                self._halt.set()
                continue
        time.sleep(1)
    self._destroy()
```

The program is called so:

```
if __name__ == 'wasp':
    w = None
    try:
        logging.info("Wasp %s",__version__)
        w = Wasp()
        w.start()
    except WaspConfException, e: # w failed to start, no need to stop
        logging.error("Configuration Error: %s",e)
    except WaspParamException, e:
        logging.error("Parameter Error: %s",e)
        if w and (w.state() == WASP_RUNNING or w.state() == WASP_PAUSED): w.stop()
    except WaspRuntimeException, e:
        logging.error("Runtime Error: %s",e)
        if w and (w.state() == WASP_RUNNING or w.state() == WASP_PAUSED): w.stop()
    except WaspException, e:
        logging.error("General Error: %s",e)
        if w and (w.state() == WASP_RUNNING or w.state() == WASP_PAUSED): w.stop()
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception("Unknown Error: %s",e)
        if w and (w.state() == WASP_RUNNING or w.state() == WASP_PAUSED): w.stop()
```

## the state function just returns an internal variable

I originally thought it might be the exceptions getting called and thereby causing stop to be called again. However, nothing is being logged. I added a state check shown above just to make sure.

Comment: Can you show us your signal handler functions?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I added the stop function to my question.

Comment: Hm, I tried implementing this without the object references and couldn't recreate the problem. Can you show us the object, or perhaps this `set()` function you're using?

Comment: Added - the whole code is a lot to add.

Comment: My best guess is that the child process you create in `_create` is having something to do with the issue. What happens in that process? Would the problem be resolved if you created the child process before changing the signal handlers?

Comment: Same thing happens. I have ignored everything in the child process with signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_IGN) for each signal. Although, you may be right, come to think of it, I don't think there was an issue until I added the child.